# Create a ToolTip inside a custom control and linked to that control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, tooltip

I have a vb.NET app with multiple forms. (This question applies to any .NET project though) Currently many have a PictureBox control on the form. I want the behavior of this control standardized, so I'm creating a custom class with setters and options and events.

However I'm stuck on the ToolTip. Previously the individual forms had their own ToolTip objects that show downloaded images, but I don't want to redefine that on each form - so I defined imageToolTip as a global variable in the control and in the OnHandleCreated method I created it and set handlers.

But they never trigger.

```
Public Class ItemPreviewBox
    Inherits PictureBox
    Private imageToolTip As ToolTip
    Private _ItemType, _ItemNum As String
    Private _ColorID As Integer
    Private _Thumb As Boolean
    Private _Label As Label = New Label
    
    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
        imageToolTip = New ToolTip With {
            .OwnerDraw = True
        }
        imageToolTip.SetToolTip(Me, "")
    
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    
        AddHandler imageToolTip.Popup, AddressOf HandlePopup
        AddHandler imageToolTip.Draw, AddressOf HandleDraw
        AddHandler Click, AddressOf HandleClick
    
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub HandlePopup(sender As ToolTip, e As PopupEventArgs)
        Log("Tooltip Popped Up")
        If _ItemType Is Nothing Then e.Cancel = True
        e.ToolTipSize = New Size(250, 200)
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub HandleDraw(sender As ToolTip, e As DrawToolTipEventArgs)
        If _ItemType Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        LogVerbose("opening image tooltip")
        e.Graphics.Clear(SystemColors.Info)
        Dim imgFileName = CacheImage(_ItemType, _ItemNum, _ColorID, _Thumb) 'Returns a string
        Log($"{e.AssociatedControl.Name} - {e.AssociatedControl.Location.X},{e.AssociatedControl.Location.Y} top={e.AssociatedControl.Top} left=top={e.AssociatedControl.Left}")
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(imgFileName), New Rectangle(0, 0, 250, 200))
    End Sub
```

The Click event (not associated with the ToolTip) triggers.

I have also tried moving the ToolTip code to the owning form's Shown event (replacing "Me" with the control's name) and it works perfectly.

Does the ToolTip need to have the Form as its parent and not the control?Is there any way to have the custom ToolTip instantiated when the custom PictureBox is?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find this in the docs for ToolTip, but according to an article on CodeProject:

> Setting a control's tooltip dynamically requires a popup event, but
> the popup events for the control will stop if SetToolTip is called
> with an empty string argument. (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/59501/Implementing-Dynamic-ToolTips-Preventing-SetToolTi)

I was setting an empty string because I was only intending to show an image and it seemed inefficient to do otherwise. Changing the SetToolTip line to

```
imageToolTip.SetToolTip(Me, "Lorem Ipsum")
```

solved the problem.